# Declaring List of multiple types in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to have a mutable list which contains multiple types, says my data type and String. 
I have my data class `MyObject`

```
data class MyObject(val date: Date?, val description: String?)
```

So I expect something like list below:

```
var myList = mutableListOf<MyObject, String>()
```

Is there any way to archive it in Kotlin?

Comment: Use mutableListOf<Any>(). You need to cast a particular element to use it.

Comment: thanks @nitinkumarp, <Any> does the trick

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a list that has the first common supertype of your two types as its type parameter, which in this case is `Any`:

```
val myList = mutableListOf<Any>()
myList.add("string")
myList.add(MyObject(null, null))
```

Of course this way you'll "lose" the type of the items that are in the list, and every time you get a list item you'll only know it by the type `Any`:

```
val item: Any = myList.get(0)
```

At this point you can make type checks to see what the type of the item is:

```
if (item is MyObject) {
    println(item.description)
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to sort any type of list i.e ArrayList<Any> ?

Answer (score 11):

In this specific case where the types are known and limited to two elements, I would use Pair:

```
var myList = mutableListOf<Pair<MyObject,String>>()
```

Full code snippet below:

```
import java.util.Date

data class MyObject(val date: Date?, val description: String?)

var myList = mutableListOf<Pair<MyObject,String>>()

   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val first = MyObject(Date(), "time1")
   val second = "info1"
   myList.add(Pair(first, second))
   println(myList[0])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no, that will be list of **Any** which is super type of every type, You can not create list of **MyObject, String**

```
import java.util.*

data class MyObject(val date: Date?, val description: String?)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      var myObject = MyObject(null, "")
      var myList = mutableListOf(myObject, "someString")
      print(myList)
}
```

Below code is not possible,

```
var myList = mutableListOf<MyObject, String>()
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead you can use sealed class feature available in kotlin. As,

```
sealed class MyNewClass{
    data class MyObject(val date: Date?, val description: String?): MyNewClass()
    data class ClassForStringData(val data: String): MyNewClass()
}

// List initialization
val newList: List<MyNewClass> = listOf(
    MyNewClass.MyObject(Date(), "Description"),
    MyNewClass.MyObject(Date(), "Description"),
    MyNewClass.ClassForStringData("New Text"),
    MyNewClass.ClassForStringData("New another Text")
)

//Access
fun accessListData(){
    val newListObject = newList[2]
    if (newListObject is MyNewClass.ClassForStringData)
        println(newListObject.data)
}
```

With sealed classes you can create a supertype whenever the child classes are known before. Hope this helpful for anyone with similar scenario.

Comment: This is a way better solution that the accept one suggesting Any

Comment: I agree sealed class is better than Any, but also has the limitation to put all data classes in the same file as the sealed class. So if somebody isn't happy with that, he can create a dummy interface and use it instead sealed class. Also I believe that in the example above sealed class could be replaced with sealed interface, it will fit better